# How to deal with Gitlab Backup Files

Tags: backup, gitlab

I have a lot of different files in my backup directory for Gitlab.
Some of them are 26MB which seems like a whole backup.
Others are 10KB. Which one should I keep and why is there two different kind of files ?

```html
ls -al backups/
total 34880
drwxr-xr-x  3 uhal uhal     4096 Mar  2 02:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 uhal uhal     4096 Jun  4  2016 ..
-rw-------  1 uhal uhal    10240 Feb 24 02:00 1487898010_gitlab_backup.tar
-rw-------  1 uhal uhal    10240 Feb 25 02:00 1487984409_gitlab_backup.tar
-rw-------  1 uhal uhal 26716160 Feb 26 02:00 1488070809_gitlab_backup.tar
-rw-------  1 uhal uhal    10240 Feb 27 02:00 1488157209_gitlab_backup.tar
-rw-------  1 uhal uhal 26716160 Feb 28 02:00 1488243609_gitlab_backup.tar
-rw-------  1 uhal uhal    10240 Feb 28 02:00 1488243610_gitlab_backup.tar
-rw-------  1 uhal uhal    10240 Mar  1 02:00 1488330010_gitlab_backup.tar
-rw-------  1 uhal uhal    10240 Mar  2 02:00 1488416410_gitlab_backup.tar
-rw-------  1 uhal uhal      146 Mar  2 02:00 artifacts.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 uhal uhal      158 Mar  2 02:00 backup_information.yml
-rw-------  1 uhal uhal      146 Mar  2 02:00 lfs.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x  4 uhal uhal     4096 Jun 15  2016 tmp
```

UPDATE : March 3rd 2017

```html
tar -xvf 1488502809_gitlab_backup.tar
backup_information.yml

tar -xvf 1488070809_gitlab_backup.tar
repositories/
repositories/marketing/
repositories/thibaut/
repositories/thibaut/jhipster-test.bundle
artifacts.tar.gz
lfs.tar.gz
backup_information.yml
```

Comment: It looks interesting, what is inside this lightweight `tar`s?

Comment: @PiotrDawidiuk Good question, I update the post. Lightweight `tar` contain only `yml` file and heavy `tar` contain data.

Answer (score 1):

- **Lightweight** `tar` are **null backup**. They contain only a **.yml** backup report saying there was nothing new to be done.
- **Heavy** `tar` are **full backup**. They are generated only when something has changed.

A change within Gitlab can happen because of an automatic process. This is why you can have a full backup generated even if nobody is connecting to your Gitlab.